# dotnet core C# Selenium get the details from the chrome developer tools Network tab?

Tags: selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, har

I am using dotnet core C# and selenium to load pages and run some tests.
I want to get the details that are displayed in the chrome developer tool network tab.
The list of resources that are loaded and the size and path for each resource, and be able to calculate the total load time and transfer size for the web page and all it's resources.

I know I could get the list of resources with javascript

```
var list = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
```

But that would not return CORS items and so isn't an exact list of all the items.

Is there a way to get the full list of resources with Selenium? or can I generate the HAR file with selenium and get the list of resources from that?

Answer (score 0):

In [Selenium 4](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/projects/2#card-15026114) there will be such option, to get the Chrome DevTools.

Till then, there're no better solutions in C# I am aware of. You could try get the data, using [JS](https://intellipaat.com/community/15106/how-to-access-network-panel-on-google-chrome-developer-tools-with-selenium):

```
String scriptToExecute = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";

    String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();
```